# Will dropping out of college be a problem in searching for software jobs

Tags: education

I am currently working in an IT company.
I want to switch into software development.
I dropped out of my BE after trying for five years.
I then got a  BSc degree through distance education which is in IT Infrastructure Mgmt.
If I do a course in software development, will the education gap be a problem when applying for a software development role

Comment: Can you please clarify? Did you complete _any_ of your previous degree efforts? If you did, seeking additional, specific education in software development would likely be seen as a positive. If you have yet to finish any of the things you've started, starting something new will likely only bring skepticism that you'll complete the new endeavor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mitigate the negative effect of quitting college in my CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/how-to-mitigate-the-negative-effect-of-quitting-college-in-my-cv)

Comment: Thanks  for checking this. I have tried to clarify the question .Please let me know if this gives a clearer picture.

Comment: I guess you should mark one of the two answers accepted. Its been too long.

Answer (score 4):

Many companies filter out applications based on qualification and experience. The gap in your education would definitely raise eyebrows. But, if you have convincing reasons for why you dropped out and also can show positives from your IT experience I guess it can be considered.

It sounds like you gave up mid-way which is not a good sign for any employer but if you can show how you overcame that period and worked towards a nice career it might work wonders! If you can highlight how you fought against the odds to restart your education and build a career, you might just stand out among the common crowd and be considered! Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a completed degree, it is very likely that seeking additional training specifically to focus on software development will help you. If you have been working since completing your degree, then there is no gap to be worried about. Employers only get worried about periods of time when you were apparently doing nothing.