# How do I address/approach a company as a university dropout?

Tags: applications, employer-relations

*Well, the title sums it up. Feel that university does not meet expectations in content, it is death-by-powerpoint and that I am not making progress.*

Trying to send emails to a few companies (i.e. open applications). There is a 2-year duration right now where there should have been a four-year university degree:

- "I just dropped out" sounds incredibly negative.
- I could try softening it over: "I'm taking a break from studying", but I think it would still be rather vague and will prompt questions at an interview, and I do not want to appear doing a bait-and-switch at that point.
- Could try to say that "university course did not meet my expectations" but that again sounds rather suspicious/discouraging, and I don't think defending myself in an initial email is a good idea.

(Location: Mainland Europe, (small) tech-related industry)

Comment: What year did you drop out? Have you actually dropped out - perhaps you enrolled in the wrong course - and can this be fixed

Comment: Will there be a 'hole' resume-wise if you never mentioned it?

Comment: @EdHeal Well, messed up another exam this afternoon. I'm still trying to switch to another course but due to the late nature of the matter I may end up taking a gap year instead, and I like to keep all doors open.

Comment: Wait for the results. Talk to your tutor. Perhaps able to retake them

Comment: Also [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41382/how-to-mitigate-the-negative-effect-of-quitting-college-in-my-cv) and [this one](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/43635/should-i-include-university-education-on-my-resume-if-i-dropped-out), which point make to the one I marked duplicate.

Comment: @DavidK those seem to go more along the line that I should only mention it a bit hidden in the CV, rather than explain my position. I was trying to go more towards the internship openings and that might seem dishonest (?) if they want people back when they graduate...

Comment: Why recommend doing a degree? I think the best bet is to wait for the results

Comment: Dick Cheney dropped out of Harvard and never advanced beyond Vice President of the United States.  Bill Gates dropped out and his software is no good.  Mark Zuckerberg dropped out and Facebook is crap.  Steve Jobs dropped out of college and Apple is rotten.  Stay in school or you'll end up like one of those losers.  They might have billions of dollars but they'll never have my magic degree paper.

Comment: See also past questions/answers about dropping out and the job market; some of them have good advice.

Comment: @emory: I love statements like those.  If you have the drive, charisma and personal ability to forge your own path then you aren't going to be on a website asking people how to convince prospective employers even though you couldn't complete 2 years of college in your chosen field you are better than candidates that actually finished school.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply list 2 years of school on the resume/CV, and then talk about your experience in your field.  Don't give a reason for dropping out on paper.  When you get asked this, AVOID saying anything about "not meeting expectations."  The hiring manager will hear this as "He will leave this job the moment he has to do something he doesn't like."

I think the "taking a break from school" is actually a much better line.  You could also simply say

> I need a job now more than I need a degree later.

Several students take a year off and get full-time work.  Students don't have much money, and any hiring manager will be able to relate to the guy who just wants a little more money in his pocket.